# Google Calendar API insert

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I trying to implement Google Calendar in one of my projects. I have already been able to get all events using the following link:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[id]/events?key=[key]

I'm now trying to implement inserting events which seems a bit harder because it keeps asking me to authenticate, but I don't want to bother my users with having to login and redirect every xx time. Also, my users don't even know the login so they won't be able to login.

This is where I'm at:

```
$event=array(
    'summary'=>'test test',
    'start'=>array(
        'dateTime'=>'2018-06-02T11:00:00',
        'timeZone'=>'Europe/Paris',
    ),
    'end'=>array(
        'dateTime'=>'2018-06-02T12:00:00',
        'timeZone'=>'Europe/Paris',
    ),
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[id]/events?key=[key]');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($event));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Is this even possible?

This is the current response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the curl response?

Comment: @Lucarnosky I have added the response.

Comment: Try add this parameter in your curl    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

Comment: @Lucarnosky unfortunately: "HTTP Basic Authentication is not supported for this API"

Comment: I think this link may help you. https://www.daimto.com/google-authentication-with-curl/

Comment: @Lucarnosky it seems to do what it says, but when applying the access_token, I'm now getting the an "Insufficient Permission" error.

Comment: According to another answer on SO, try to revoke access to your webapp from  https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens and then set it again. It should work

Comment: @Lucarnosky unfortunately that doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I'm sorry man, I've finished the ideas :)

Comment: @Lucarnosky well thanks anyway for getting me 1 (or 2) steps closer to my goal!